# Set notation: 'exclusively divisible by'

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation

What is the best way to write 'exclusively divisible by' a given number in terms of set notation? eg: the set of natural numbers that are divisible by $2$ and only $2$; the set of natural numbers that are divisible by $3$ and only $3$; $\dots 5$, $7\dots$ etc.

Comment: What do you mean, "exclusively divisible by"?  Every positive integer can be divided by at least two different positive integers, except $1$.  Thus no integer is exclusively divisible by $2^1$, or by $2^2$, etc.

Comment: And what does "where $n \to \infty$" mean?

Comment: Perhaps by "exclusively divisible by $2^k$" you mean, divisible by $2^k$ but not by $2^n$ for any $n > k$?  I assume your question is interesting, but you need to be more precise.

Comment: This is usually written $p^k \mid\mid a$, provided that you mean that $p^k$ divides $a$ but $p^{k+1}$ does not, where $p$ is a prime.

Comment: @  Andreas Caranti, many thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a prime natural number $p,$ it seems that the set (let's call it $\Bbb D_p$) of natural numbers "exclusively divisible by $p$" (according to your description) would be:

$$\Bbb D_p=\left\{n\in\Bbb N:\exists k\in\Bbb N\left(n=p^k\right)\right\}$$

For example, $$\begin{align}\Bbb D_2 &= \left\{n\in\Bbb N:\exists k\in\Bbb N\left(n=2^k\right)\right\}\\ &= \left\{2^1,2^2,2^3,2^4,\dots\right\}\\ &= \{2,4,8,16,\dots\}.\end{align}$$

**Nota Bene**: I assume in this answer that your natural numbers do *not* include $0.$ If $0$ *is* a natural number by your definition, then we will need to alter the definition of $\Bbb D_p$ above, since while $1=p^0,$ we certainly can't say that $1$ is divisible by $p.$ Instead, we will say:

$$\Bbb D_p=\left\{n\in\Bbb N:\exists k\in\Bbb N\left[\left(n=p^k\right)\wedge(k\ne0)\right]\right\}$$

Comment: So would I be correct in assuming that this describes the set of all primes and prime powers?

Comment: Actually, no. If we denote the set if primes by $\Bbb P,$ then the set of primes and prime powers would be $$\left\{n\in\Bbb N:\exists p\in\Bbb P, k\in\Bbb N\left(n=p^k\right)\right\}.$$ I will alter my post to make this clearer.

Comment: OK, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The natural numbers are an example of a “ Euclidean Ring”. A ring is almost a "field" but doesn't have a multiplicative inverse, and the Euclidean property as applied to natural numbers means that any number a can be written as a = q.b + r. The Euclidean property has a corresponding but slightly more complicated definition for rings in general.

In any ring an “ideal” is a subset of the ring which is closed wrt addition, and  “strongly closed” wrt multiplication, i.e. any element of the ideal multiplied by any element of the ring is an element of the ideal.

A property of ideals in Euclidean rings is that all the elements of an ideal have a greatest common divisor (GCD).

So, the numbers in N which are all divisible by 2 (or 3 ,..) are “ideals” of the "Euclidean ring" of natural numbers of the form 2N, 3N, etc where 2N is the set of all numbers of the form 2 (= GCD) x n in N.

Comment: All of the things you're saying here are correct. They are not really relevant, though (as far as I can tell).

Comment: Problem is "exclusively divisible" isn't really defined. I took it as "divisible", in which case answer is more relevant.